# woocommerce_review_order_before_payment hook not working

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, themes

I want to show something on the checkout page from one of my plugins using hook. After updating to WordPress 6.4.1 it is not working, but in the previous version, it was working fine. I don't understand why it's not working now!! If anyone knows, please help.

[image: My code is]

[image: In wp old version working]

[image: It's wp new version]

Comment: You have this issue because WC use a react template to display the checkout page.

Comment: Oh! How can I show any text on the checkout page? Can you help me?

Comment: It helps a lot (also for searchability) if you post your source code as text (in code blocks) rather than as a screenshot.

Comment: If you want to use wp hook on woocommerce checkout page, I advise you to get rid of your current checkout block and use the [woocommerce_checkout] shortcode instead.